# Get Notification even when app is not running

Tags: notifications, broadcastreceiver

Hello All Can you please help me how to get notification on a specific date even when app is not in running state, Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate the exact date and transfer into long type. Set that time in Notification. Looks like:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); // example, you should revise.
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_icon, context.getString(R.string.app_name), time);
manager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
```